Unexpected import warning when import a submodule in a .pyd file in VSCode
(
I don't know whether I should tag this question with vscode, because I'm not sure if it is just a VSCode problem, or it's also due to something in python importing or pybind, or even it's just because my irregular coding.
So please inform me to revise the tag if necessary.
)
I'm working on a project based on a .pyd module compiled by pybind11 from C++.
When I tried to directly import a class in submodule with from {.pyd directory}.{.pyd name}.{submodule name} import {class name}, VSCode warns me that

Import "{.pyd directory}.{.pyd name}.{submodule name}" could not be resolved from source
Pylance(reportMissingModuleSource)

Here's a specific example:
(project folder)
├─core
│  ├─__init__.py
│  ├─pybind11module.pyd
│  ├─pybind11module
│  │  ├─__init__.pyi
│  │  ├─submodule.pyi
│  │  └─...
│  └-...
└─main.py

The *.pyis are generated by pybind11-stubgen.
The single .pyd is generated by pybind11, with multiple submodules in it.
When I write
from core.pybind11module.submodule import a_class

VSCode warns me that core.pybind11module.submodule cannot be resolved, though it can show docstrings of submodule and a_class in .pyis.
I'm now just wondering about what VSCode is trying to warn me, and how can I avoid this warning?

By the way, I've also found a inconvenient way to avoid the warning. Still take the example above, if I
import pybind11module.submodule as submodule

in core/__init__.py and
from core import submodule

then I can call submodule.a_class without any warning or error, though codes may be cumbersome under such solution.
